# Loop recording the directx output in C++/C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, video-capture

I need to loop record the Desktop/DirectX output so that I always have an approximately even amount of video data, say the last 30 seconds, which I can then save when needed.

So far I have only found simply recording to a file, but I would like to record to some kind of circular MemoryStream, producing a playable video file only when requested.

If anyone has expertise in this I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

That's right.  You use a circular buffer that is large enough to hold 30 seconds of frame data.  In your capture thread you just copy directly into the next frame in the buffer.  And once you've filled the buffer, you just loop around to the start and begin filling again.  The next available frame is always the oldest.

If you want, you can maintain a head/tail index.  But it's easier to just keep track of the next available index and a flag to say whether the buffer is full (if the buffer is not full, then the next available index is also the number of frames that you have available).

When you write the data out to disk, you either need to stop capture, or ensure that you can write fast enough.  I/O optimizations are important here - use unbuffered writes in blocks that are multiples of a disk sector size.  On some systems you can take advantage of full optimization if you  also allocate your frame data to a sector-aligned memory address.

If your I/O is slower than your capture rate, you will need to maintain a buffer that is larger than 30 seconds.  Make it as large as you like.  Always start write the oldest frame first.  To find the oldest frame, just a little modulo arithmetic will do:

```
firstFrameIdx = (bufSize + nextFrameIdx - numberOfSeconds * framesPerSecond) % bufSize
```

Of course, you could always just copy the buffer into new memory and then write it out as slow as you like.

Comment: So much for the theory, I still have no idea what apis/frameworks I have to use to capture and encode in memory. As I said, everything I found was either 'take screenshot' or 'save video to HDD'

Comment: Hmmm, you didn't explain yourself very well.  It sounded to me like you had written code to do this stuff and wanted to know how to keep a back-buffer to write out frame history on demand.  You haven't even said what you are recording.  Is it the output of your own application, or are you trying to capture the entire screen?

Comment: As I said, recording to file is easy and any library can do that. But since no library records directly into a buffer I will need to do it myself, hence the question. It's supposed to be the whole screen. Saving the frames in memory uncompressed gets way too large, so I need to save them in a circular buffer while compressing them somehow...